# How to access an external file

Tags: networking, remote

I have a Raspberry Pi for mining. Important informations are written to the file `/home/pi/minerlog.log`.

Now I have another Raspberry Pi for controlling the miner. I need to access the minerlog file and read its content.

The two Raspberry Pis are in the same network(wifi).

What's the easiest way to read this external file?

Comment: Please define "best way".  Without knowing what you mean by "best way" the question is unanswerable.

Comment: "easiest" does not help.  I might find all sorts of things easy which you would find hard to impossible (and vice versa).

Comment: How about the File Transfer Protocol?

Comment: Already got it thanks. I was thinking about ftp but its difficult to automate the process... I'm using scp now. Much simpler..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of allowing access to files from multiple machines. However, you will need the system that owns the files to cooperate.

1. **Copy the files over the network.** This is the easiest to say, but might not be the best. But, depending on your needs, it will work and it's not difficult to set up. You could set a cron job that would copy the log every five minutes using "scp" (secure copy - it's available with "ssh").
2. **Store the log files on a shared disk.** This is the easiest one to set up and it might cause the least network traffic, depending on how often the logs are written to.
3. **Rsyslogd** is designed to handle *nix log files. This is a service, which means you have to configure it. However, it affords one of the best, in my opinion, options: you can put the log file into a database for shared access. This gives you a lot of options to read the data.

I'm sure that there are a lot of other ways to do this, but these three work.

Comment: command `scp` helped!! I use it in combination with `sshpass` to bypass the password with Python. Answer accepted